# 2D Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform Bounds

Tags: fourier-analysis, image-processing

My professor for a computer vision class introduced the 2-D Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform (in the context of images) as the following:

$$X(\omega_1, \omega_2)=\sum_{n_1}\sum_{n_2}x(n_1,n_2)e^{j\omega_1n_1}e^{j\omega_2n_2}$$

and

$$x(n_1,n_2)=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}X(\omega_1,\omega_2)e^{j\omega_1n_1}e^{j\omega_2n_2}d\omega_1 d\omega_2,$$

where $x$ is the original image and $X$ is the Fourier Transform of $x$.

In the IFT, there are bounds from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, and I'm not seeing why this is the case; it seems like to me they should be from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, because in the FT formula, $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ can take on any value, so we need to integrate over all those values. I was told that the complex exponential in the integral is periodic, so we don't need to integrate over the entire space. This doesn't seem like a complete explanation to me — I think it's because $X(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ is also periodic? (Please confirm whether this is true.) In that case, the bounds would make sense since the period seems to be $2\pi$.

If it is true, I was wondering why most versions of the 2-D FT/IFT that I've found on the internet integrate from $-\infty,+\infty$.

Comment: ... just because you are limited by the screen, otherwise said, all your functions are implicitly multiplied by $Rect_{[-\pi,\pi]} \times Rect_{[-\pi,\pi] }(x,y)$...

Comment: We can still plug any $\omega_1,\omega_2$ into the Fourier Transform that we would like though, I think? So the frequency domain still spans the entire infinite range. And I actually don't really understand why the -infinity to infinity bounds exist if the FT is periodic.

Comment: I hadn't paid attention to the fact that you have a $\sum$ symbol in a direction and an $\int$ symbol in the orther direction. **This isn't possible**. Either you work with a continuous Fourier transform, with $\int$ definition in both directions (direct and inverse) or with the discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) in both directions with $\sum$.

Comment: I noticed that as well, but why isn't it allowed? Both directions seem sensible to me because the FT outputs a continuous function of frequencies with a discrete input, and the IFT can be evaluated at discrete points with a continuous frequency domain input.

Comment: In your last comment, you are mentionning the Shannon theorem, which is another thing. This does not prevent the fact that the DFT (also called incorrectly FFT) maps a n-dimensionnal (temporal) signal onto a n-dimensionnal (frequency) "signal".